# How to understand "Beat the jolt, check the volt"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

"Beat the jolt, check the volt" is an electrical safe slogan.

For example: https://sloganshub.org/electrical-safety-slogans/#google_vignette

I know "volt" is the unit of electric potential and electromotive force, and I can understand "check the volt".

What's the meaning of "beat the jolt"? I recognize the three words <strike>respectively</strike> individually, but fail to comprehend the three-word sentence.

Comment: This "slogan" is neither idiomatic nor syntactically valid. "Beat the jolt" has no currency outside of this slogan, and the suggested way to avoid being electrocuted should be *check the **voltage***, not ***...volt.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But "check the voltage" doesn't rhyme :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Beat the joltage.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A "jolt" is sudden movement, as you might get from an electric shock.  To "beat" something means to defeat it.

You can "beat" an electric shock by checking if a wire is live, so you don't get a jolt from touching it.

In this slogan, the use of a "natural" or clear expression like "avoid the electric shock" is replaced by something shorter that rhymes "beat the jolt".  Slogans (like song lyrics or poetry) are not meant to be natural English.

Comment: When I was studying electronics, we learned 'It's volts that jolt, but mils that kill'. Mils (milliamperes or milliamps, thousandths of one amp) are units of current. A high voltage (over 50 V) combined with a current of 10 to 20 mA may make you jump, but a current of at least 100 mA is necessary to kill you.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Speaking as an electrical engineer, that's a dangerous misconception. Depending on what parts of you the current goes through, it can take *much* less than 100 mA to kill; if it goes through your heart, for instance, it's possible for less than 10 mA to stop your heart.

Comment: @Hearth - Yes, indeed. I was thinking of something like across the body, say hand to hand or foot.  7mA directly across the heart can kill, but I suspect you'd be talking about via a catheter? As little as 30 mA across the chest at 50/60 Hz can induce ventricular fibrillation.

Comment: @Hearth Accidental electric shocks rarely go through the heart, and that's what the slogans are geared towards.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The same current flows through an entire circuit.  The current that goes from one hand to another largely passes through the heart without any other intervention.  That's the reason for the old electricians' rule of keeping one hand in your pocket when making measurements.  Hand-to-foot currents will still pass through the torso, and the heart can still be affected (but marginally less lethal than hand-to-hand).

Comment: @Hearth Snappy catchphrases tend to go light on making sure every single base is covered.

Comment: @Flater I have no objection to the catchphrase (well, none relevant to this discussion, anyway); my objection was to Michael's statement that "at least 100 mA is necessary to kill you".

Comment: Wondering if the 100mA figure is a historical rule of thumb. Perhaps from a time before 120/240VAC became the norm in households? Apparently, in the late 1800s, 40V was a thing for incandescent lighting...

But to add to the actual topic: phrases like the one asked about by OP or mentioned by Michael Harvey also have mnemonic value: anything that rhymes will find its way into your memory much more easily.

Comment: I wasn’t familiar with this slogan, but intuitively, I don’t think ‘defeat’ is the right sense of _beat_. Defeating the jolt would be what you did if you just ‘took it on the chin’ and powered through until you didn’t feel it anymore. I think the more relevant sense of _beat_ here is ‘take action to avoid (difficulty or inconvenience)’, what you do when you leave early to _beat traffic_.

Comment: The amount of current it takes to kill a healthy adult might be very different from the amount it takes to push a sick person over the edge. Correspondingly, standards for leakage on medical equipment are more stringent than for general electronics (as low as 0.15mA vs. 0.5mA). Obviously both those are much, much less than would typically cause a fatal shock (because we don't want anyone at all to die if the leakage is within spec).

Comment: @Hearth more to the point, practical electrical sources are far more likely to behave like constant-voltage sources rather than constant-current sources. As such, to a first-order approximation, the current one gets exposed to *will be determined by voltage anyway*. In practice it's actually worse than that; high voltages can cause the body's tissues to break down and decrease their electrical resistance.

Comment: I once received a very unpleasant 120V shock down the side of my body while trying to plug or unplug something into an outlet in an overhead hanging fixture. The one-hand rule likely protected me from the shock being much more dangerous; but it also made it much more difficult to manipulate the plug. This was in a university lab and might well have involved an old-school 2-prong plug - terrible design, and line voltage honestly wasn't even necessary to demonstrate the concept we were studying.